# How to use uiautomator without source code

Tags: java, android, automation, android-uiautomator

I am new to UIautomator testing and could not figure out how to setup a UI test, when only having the .apk file.

[Online Tutorial](https://developer.android.com) and other examples do not show how to use my 3P .apk file. I know that in Appium one can just add a file/directory and name to desired capabilities and server will install it.

Answer (score 0):

UiAutomator can be used to create user interface (UI) test that involves user interactions across multiple apps thus these tests are not related to any APK in particular but to the device as a whole.

You can install the APKs first and run whatever you want as a test later. Source code for those apps is not needed.

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) allows you to create python scripts and even supports installing APKs as a precondition.

For example

```
culebra --install-apk=FILENAME
```

creates such script.

If you want to do it in Java you can invoke `pm install` if you have previously copied the files.